# clear the material UI text field Value in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to clear the materialUI textfield value in react?

Check the below code -

```
<TextField
  hintText=""
  ref={(node) => this._toField = node}
  onChange={this.changeToText}
  floatingLabelText="To*"
  floatingLabelFixed={true}
  fullWidth={true}
/>
```

I'm using the raisedButton while pressing it validate the above field. If the field has error then displaying the error message. If not, then we need to clear the input. But how can we clear the input text?

Answer (score 7):

if you are using a stateless functional component then you can use react hooks.

Also make sure you are using inputRef

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

let MyFunctional = props => {
  let textInput = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            textInput.current.value = "";
          }, 100);
        }}
      >
        Focus TextField
      </Button>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        required
        inputRef={textInput}
        name="firstName"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
        label="First Name"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: this is the answer, OP is using ref, not inputRef

Answer (score 0):

There is a `value` property that you have to pass to the TextField component.
check example below:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  state = {value: ''}
  resetValue = () => {
    this.setState({value: ''});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          ...
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <button onClick={this.resetValue}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import { Button, Container, InputBase } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const ClearText = ()=> {

    const [text , setText] = useState("")

const clearTextField = () => setText("")

    return (
        <Container>
        <InputBase 
        value={text ? text : ""}
        onChange={(e)=>setText(e.target.value)}
        />


        <Button onClick={clearTextField} > Clear </Button>
        </Container>
    )
};

export default ClearText;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score -1):

You need to, somehow, store the input's value. State seems to be an initial approach in this case. Whenever the text changes, you have to update the state. Same applies when you click the button and click the input's value afterwards:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
  }

  handleClick() {
    // validation...
    this.setState({ value: '' })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click-me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```